# Viewing Images with Tensorboard, is there a way to synchronize "steps"?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard to visualize some network results. Conveniently, it adds a slider to skip through steps - but to "synchronize" the images, I have to manually slide to the right step in every image. E.g. here I slided to `step 32` for `predicition_c0_1` (*left image*). If I wanted the corresponding `prediction_c0` (*right image*), I'd have to manually slide to it.

**Is there a way to synchronize sliding through steps across all images automatically?**

[image: tensorboard images]